# Backup photographs in the cloud with Telegram?

Tags: storage, backup, file

I would like to make a backup in the cloud of my photographs (about 128gb) while I am traveling.

Telegram is free and I can send the original pictures to my second phone number.

But I don't know if It has any limitation (life time of the files, number of files....) Have any of you used it for that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about features of a secure messaging app, not about photography.

Comment: It is a question about how can this app be useful for all the photographers community at the backup time

Comment: I understand, but this isn’t a photography-specific question. The service is not one that caters to photographers or photographic uses; your use-case would be identical if you wanted to store audio files, or PDF documents, etc., while traveling. While it’s true that photographers _could_ use the service as a temporary file storage while traveling, one could _also_ just store files (photos, etc.) as attachments to draft emails with any of several free email services (as an example of using a service not as really intended). But that doesn’t elevate this to be on-topic for Photo-SE, I’m afraid.

Comment: I don't know anything about Telegram other than it is an instant message app. Does it compress images when you send them? I know that WhatsApp does. If you want to backup photographs, I think you should look into a proper backup solution. Why risk it? Aren't your photographs worth the what a proper solution would cost?

Comment: You do not need a second number with telegram, anyways: there is a `saved messages` category that 'sends' messages to your own number. I do not know about storage limits, though.

Comment: does telegram really use cloud space? doesn't it just store the data on the target phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a second number to store files with Telegram. You can send to your self any kind of file.
There is also an option to avoid compress an image when you send it. The option says: *send image as a file*.

But, Telegram is a messsage app, not a storage app. Their data policy can change any time, and your files could be deleted/modified without even notify you.
There is not any feature to allow you classify files, download massively or search for a particular file.

I don't recomend you to use Telegram as a serious backup alternative.

Answer (score 4):

While this may be a convent transfer mechanism (assuming the app does have the feature of sending unmodified originals without recompressing or downsizing), it is *not* a backup. Even if Telegram happens to provide adequate storage and no time limits *today*, there is no guarantee that they will tomorrow, or for the rest of the trip. They could literally decide to delete them all at any moment. Or they could just go out of business. They've made no promises to store your data and have no obligation to you to do so.

If your photos have any value or significance to you, this is or any similar *Life Hacks!* approaches are just not worth it. You should find a real backup solution.